# Typescript key-value pair where key is custom type

Tags: typescript

I have the following key-value pair and it is being used for a filtering system. When we apply a filter, we could merge it with all the current ones, or just apply it with resetting the previous.

```
type MINE = "mine"
type BOOKMARKED = "bookmarked"
type TEXT_QUERY = "textQuery"
type JobType = "type"

export type PossibleFilterKeys = MINE | BOOKMARKED | TEXT_QUERY | JobType

type Filter = {
    [key in PossibleFilterKeys]: string;
};
```

Then I have the following prototype of a function:

```
const apply = (filter: Filter) => void
```

When we use it:

```
// name: PossibleFilterKeys,
// value: string,
apply({[name]: value})
```

It triggers: `TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Filter'.   Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Filter': mine, bookmarked, textQuery, type`

I want to apply a filter, its key could be one of the `PossibleFilterKeys` type, but it throws the error above.

Why does this happen?

Comment: please share reproducable example

Comment: Thanks to @31piy the problem was solved. As he said, we could do: `[key in PossibleFilterKeys]?: string` but we also can use the Partial utility: `apply: (filter: Partial<Filter>) => void`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with this statement:

```
type Filter = {
    [key in PossibleFilterKeys]: string;
};
```

The above declares that `Filter` must contain all the keys of `PossibleFilterKeys`. You can make those optional by the following syntax:

```
type Filter = {
    [key in PossibleFilterKeys]?: string; // <-- Place a question mark
};
```

Comment: Yeah it works, thank you! Another way is: `apply: (filter: Partial<Filter>) => void`

Comment: @Stephan882 -- I don't think that's a good choice. Your way just solves one part, i.e. to call the function with a partial object. What about creating the `Filter` objects? Those still require all the keys.

Comment: Well, you are right. Currently I'm not creating anything. We call the function, pass an object, and merge or replace the current one. Thank you again, I do really appreciate your help!